# Nested group in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, ios14, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm struggling to get the layout I want using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. The following image is what I'm trying to do (along with my calculations of fractionalWidth/Height which I can only assume are incorrect based on the result I'm getting.

[Nested group with Leading Item - design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ9JL.jpg)

The code I've written to try and produce the above is as below:

```
                let leadingItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
                let nestedGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(3/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
                let nestedItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/2))
                let outerGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(3/5))
                
                let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: leadingItemSize)
                let nestedItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: nestedItemSize)
                let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: nestedGroupSize, subitem: nestedItem, count: 3)
                
                
                let outerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: outerGroupSize, subitems: [leadingItem, nestedGroup])
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: outerGroup)
                
                return section
```

This is producing the undesired result as in the below image:

[Nested group with Leading Item - Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxItR.jpg)

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong and help me to figure out how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to fix it by adding in a vertical group that contains two of the horizontal groups. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it and would really appreciate if anyone could verify and explain why this is correct, or to explain what the best way would have been to do this. My resultant code is as below:

```
let leadingItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let nestedHorizontalGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/2))
let nestedHorizontalItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let outerGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(3/5))
let nestedVerticalGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(3/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))

let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: leadingItemSize)
leadingItem.contentInsets.trailing = 1
let nestedHorizontalItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: nestedHorizontalItemSize)
let nestedHorizontalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: nestedHorizontalGroupSize, subitem: nestedHorizontalItem, count: 3)
nestedHorizontalGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(1)

let nestedVerticalGroup =  NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: nestedVerticalGroupSize, subitem: nestedHorizontalGroup, count: 2)
nestedVerticalGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(1)

let outerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: outerGroupSize, subitems: [leadingItem, nestedVerticalGroup])
outerGroup.contentInsets = .init(top: 2, leading: 0, bottom: 2, trailing: 0)

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: outerGroup)
section.contentInsets = .init(top: 2, leading: 50, bottom: 16, trailing: 50)

return section
```

The final result is as in the below image:

[Nested horizontal group in vertical group with leading item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nA2J.jpg)